# .htaccess redirect multiple URLs to one .html

Tags: .htaccess

I'm trying to have a URL structure like this:
www.mydomain.com/aaa/bbb/ccc
www.mydomain.com/aaa/ddd/eee
www.mydomain.com/aaa/fff/ggg

All of the above url's should redirect to: www.mydomain.com/aaa.html

Today I use this in .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.*)/$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.html -f
RewriteRule (.*)/$ $1.html [L]
```

If I try to input: www.mydomain.com/aaa/bbb/ccc in a browser, the server will lookup: www.mydomain.com/aaa.html/bbb/ccc and not www.mydomain.com/aaa.html

Comment: `RewriteRule ^/?aaa(.*)/?$ aaa.html [L]`

Comment: It looks like this should work, but something strange is happening. If the file aaa.html dosen't exists, then my browser tells me: "The requested URL /aaa.html was not found on this server". But if the file aaa.html exists, then I get: "The requested URL /aaa.html/bbb/ccc was not found on this server."

Comment: OK. This works. As long as I don't redirect to aaa.html. Then I guess the other RewriteCond "intereferes". But I can redirect to aaa.shtml or aaa.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have  similar scenario where I like to redirect all requests from permanently moved directories to new location (in my case new domain)

```
RewriteRule ^aaa\/?(.*)$ "http\:\/\/mydomain\.com\/aaa.html" [R=301,L]
```

Take note of the 301, "Moved Permanently" code. That seam to require using the full url in the redirect path.

Hope this can help you.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I don't really need a 301, I want this to be transparent to the user. 

I think the solution should work, but this is on a subfolder, and the parent folder also have a .htaccess that seems to be overriding the one that I'm changing. I still get "www.mydomain.com/aaa.html/bbb not found", I can't delete the .htaccess in the parent folder, is there something else I can to to stop it from beeing applied to my subfolder?